# suppress Listing: # in code blocks with tcolorbox

Tags: captions, listings, tcolorbox, labels, minted

Hi there I've been recently experimenting with code blocks in `LaTex` and I had the need to have my code blocks with captions and a label to catch them once clicked on the appropriate link in the document. See a MWE below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}


\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=electricultramarine,
    filecolor=.,
    linkcolor=maroon,
    urlcolor=smokyblack,
    linktoc=all
}
\definecolor{cobalt}{rgb}{0.0, 0.28, 0.67}
\definecolor{maroon}{rgb}{0.69, 0.19, 0.38}
\captionsetup[listing]{labelformat=empty,labelsep=none,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false}

\begin{document}

...

For a description of the code used and specific versions for the tools, along with data availability, readers are referred to the appropriate section for the \hyperref[listing:samtools]{\textcolor{cobalt}{\textbf{Code and Data Availability}}} in the document.

...
\newpage

\begin{listing}[H]
\caption{Reads extraction from BAM files with \texttt{samtools 1.18-12-g147ac2f}.}
\begin{minted}[frame=lines,framesep=2mm,baselinestretch=1.2,
bgcolor=lightgray,fontsize=\footnotesize,linenos,breaklines]{bash}
# reads line by line a file list where paths for all samples are stored
NAMES=$1
d=$(sed -n "$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID"p $NAMES)

# convert BAM to FASTQ and sort the latter for all samples
samtools fastq -c 9 --reference /leonardo_scratch/large/userexternal/mungaro0/hs37d5.fa -1 $d/R1.fastq.gz -2 $d/R2.fastq.gz -@ 32 $d/*.bam
samtools sort -n $d/R1.fastq.gz -o $d/R1_sorted.fastq.gz -@ 32
samtools sort -n $d/R2.fastq.gz -o $d/R2_sorted.fastq.gz -@ 32
rm $d/R1.fastq.gz $d/R2.fastq.gz
\end{minted}
\label{listing:samtools}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

Now this is great, however, once the code blocks span over a page in length I'm forced to add this to the preamble, as per one post which suggested how to fix this problem:
`\newenvironment{longlisting}{\captionsetup{type=listing}}{}`.

Again, the problem was solved if not for an *undefull \vbox 10000pt on line x*; apparently, originating from the **bgcolor** not being suited for this purpose... So, I looked up a bit and found out that `\tcolorbox` is a much better alternative for these cases with an overall better look for code blocks and more features, such as breaking blocks through pages. Below a MWE using `\tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}


\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=electricultramarine,
    filecolor=.,
    linkcolor=maroon,
    urlcolor=smokyblack,
    linktoc=all
}
\definecolor{cobalt}{rgb}{0.0, 0.28, 0.67}
\definecolor{maroon}{rgb}{0.69, 0.19, 0.38}
\captionsetup[listing]{labelformat=empty,labelsep=none,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings, minted, xparse, breakable, skins}
\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{\textcolor[rgb]{1,1,1}{\scriptsize\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \newtcblisting[blend into=listings]{bash}[2][]{%
        title=#2,
        detach title,
        coltitle=black,
        comment above* listing,
        comment=\raggedright\tcbtitle,
        breakable,
        minted language=bash,
        minted style=murphy, colback=lightgray, enhanced, frame hidden,
        minted options={fontsize=\footnotesize, tabsize=2, breaklines, autogobble,
        linenos, numbersep=5pt, frame=lines, framesep=2mm, baselinestretch=1.2},
        overlay={
            \begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!75] (frame.south west)
        rectangle ([xshift=5.1mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}
        }       
    }
}

\begin{document}

...

For a description of the code used and specific versions for the tools, along with data availability, readers are referred to the appropriate section for the \hyperref[listing:samtools]{\textcolor{cobalt}{\textbf{Code and Data Availability}}} in the document.

...

\newpage

\begin{bash}{Reads extraction from BAM files with \texttt{samtools 1.18-12-g147ac2f}.}
# reads line by line a file list where paths for all samples are stored
NAMES=$1
d=$(sed -n "$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID"p $NAMES)

# convert BAM to FASTQ and sort the latter for all samples
samtools fastq -c 9 --reference /leonardo_scratch/large/userexternal/mungaro0/hs37d5.fa -1 $d/R1.fastq.gz -2 %$d/R2.fastq.gz -@ 32 $d/*.bam
samtools sort -n $d/R1.fastq.gz -o $d/R1_sorted.fastq.gz -@ 32
samtools sort -n $d/R2.fastq.gz -o $d/R2_sorted.fastq.gz -@ 32
rm $d/R1.fastq.gz $d/R2.fastq.gz
\end{bash}

\end{document}
```

This is fantastic and provide a much better look to the plain implementation as per before, *BUT* for the sake of me I cannot find a way to remove the **Listing: #** from the title as in the `\minted` example... also, I don't know how to add a clickable label...

Lastly, as you might have noticed these are BASH code blocks, for some reason, `LaTex` complains about the `$` sign and I cannot figure out why or how to solve this. You should be able to test everything in Overleaf, which is what I'm using.
Sorry for the long text, any help is much appreciated!!!

**EDIT** for @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
[image]

**EDIT 2** for @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
[image]

Comment: Can you make your last code fragment compilable?

Comment: Sure, apologies. I'll fix it right away.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz it should be working now.

Comment: Did you test it?

Comment: Apologies, I messed up copying the text. Let me know whether you can run it now. It has been tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- if you want your link to be clickable, you need to give a label to the `tcolorbox`
- if you want to remove the `Listing #:`, you can use `blend before title code={}`. However the numbering might be very confusing if you mix this with normal listings...

---

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}

\documentclass[12pt]{report}


\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=electricultramarine,
    filecolor=.,
    linkcolor=maroon,
    urlcolor=smokyblack,
    linktoc=all
}
\definecolor{cobalt}{rgb}{0.0, 0.28, 0.67}
\definecolor{maroon}{rgb}{0.69, 0.19, 0.38}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings, minted, xparse, breakable, skins}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \newtcblisting[
        blend into=listings
    ]{bash}[2][]{%
        title=#2,
        detach title,
        coltitle=black,
        comment above* listing,
        comment=\raggedright\tcbtitle,
        breakable,
        minted language=bash,
        minted style=murphy, colback=lightgray, enhanced, frame hidden,
        minted options={fontsize=\footnotesize, tabsize=2, breaklines, autogobble,
        linenos, numbersep=5pt, frame=lines, framesep=2mm, baselinestretch=1.2},
        overlay={
            \begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!75] (frame.south west)
        rectangle ([xshift=5.1mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}
        },
        blend before title code={},
        #1       
    }
}

\begin{document}

...

For a description of the code used and specific versions for the tools, along with data availability, readers are referred to the appropriate section for the \hyperref[listing:samtools]{\textcolor{cobalt}{\textbf{Code and Data Availability}}} in the document.
...

\newpage

\begin{bash}[label=listing:samtools]{Reads extraction from BAM files with \texttt{samtools 1.18-12-g147ac2f}.}
# reads line by line a file list where paths for all samples are stored
NAMES=$1
d=$(sed -n "$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID"p $NAMES)

# convert BAM to FASTQ and sort the latter for all samples
samtools fastq -c 9 --reference /leonardo_scratch/large/userexternal/mungaro0/hs37d5.fa -1 $d/R1.fastq.gz -2 %$d/R2.fastq.gz -@ 32 $d/*.bam
samtools sort -n $d/R1.fastq.gz -o $d/R1_sorted.fastq.gz -@ 32
samtools sort -n $d/R2.fastq.gz -o $d/R2_sorted.fastq.gz -@ 32
rm $d/R1.fastq.gz $d/R2.fastq.gz
\end{bash}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see this makes perfect sense. For the numbering is not an issue as I do not intend to add any other listing nor I'm going to have a `\listoflistings`. However, if I copy paste the code in Overleaft I'm prompted with several errors/warning messages and cannot produce the PDF. Is there anything specific I need to do?

Comment: @Matteo I don't get any errors with the code form my answer https://www.overleaf.com/read/kvcyvgxpfyww#60bb1c

Comment: Indeed, I see. I attach in the message above what Overleaft prompts me with and maybe you can have a look. I will work on it in my main document but, in the meantime, I accept the solutions as this is awesome!

Comment: @Matteo You could check if you use the newest texlive version and/or recompile from scratch. If this does not help, you should ask a new question

Comment: yup `recompile from scratch` does the trick. I was confused since I also was using texlive 2023 ;). One last note, what about the annoying issue with the `$` sign in the BASH code block?

Comment: @Matteo What's with the `$` sign?

Comment: it gives a `unclosed $ found at \end{bash}` warning (error) which does not affect compiling but leaves a red mark next to the line number...

Comment: @Matteo I don't get any such warning or error

Comment: as per before, I added an image in the main post. Maybe you have a better understanding of what's going on, or if there is any option/flag I have to switch in my Overleaf. Thanks!

Comment: No warning or error for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwhYd.png

Comment: Yeah, that's so weird... I wonder if it's impacted by the whole lot of other packages I've loaded. But in principle it shouldn't be since I tested the script you shared in a new document and the issue persists.