# unknown issue with tcolorbox bash code

Tags: listings, tcolorbox, minted, code, bash

Hi there I've been recently, thanks to the help received in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/713135/suppress-listing-in-code-blocks-with-tcolorbox/713138?noredirect=1#comment1772462_713138), updated all my code blocks to a much nicer and neat view using `tcolorbox`. Unfortunately, for some reason, two of them show the following:

[image]

were the top dot above the one I'm pointing to says: "unclosed $ found at \end{bash}". Now, if helps I can report the whole preamble I used for `tcolorbox` which is, however, available at the post I linked above. It seems who helped me didn't face this problem, so I wonder why is this happening... it doesn't hurt or prevent the code from compiling but it is just strange!

Upon looking a bit into what `arara` does, it might be related to that? But again, I'm quite new to LaTex and really can't figure out by myself the root for this problem... if anyone that came across it could help, it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: this looks like a problem of  the syntax highlighting your editor. It gets confused by the $ on the line before.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I see, I also had the same feeling since I tried and removed the `$` for only realizing the problem was switching to the one prior... Is there a fix for this? I told `minted` to use the BASH syntax, so in theory this should not happen. Am I wrong and should go for something else when using BASH in LaTex? Let me know, thanks. To be noted, I'm working in Overleaf.

Comment: ask the overleaf support. Their editor has to handle that.

Comment: I will, thanks!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer hi there. Sorry, for being a bit late on this; however, for whoever else facing the same problem the trick is to wrap the `\begin{<language>} ... \end{<language>}` within a *%%begin novalidate* and *%%end novalidate*, respectively. Alternatively, from the Menu of Overleaft you can turn off the Code Check. This "exotic" sequences, as defined by the Overleaft Support Team, are apparently not well-handled by the LaTeX parser.